# python error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha1'"

Tags: linux, python-2.7, hashlib

i need your help,

How to correct an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha1',

When I start the command example import random or import hashlib I get such a result

```
root@thinkad:~# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "hashlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha1'
>>> import math
>>> import hashlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha1'
>>>
```

Comment: Could you run `import hashlib; print dir(hashlib), hashlib.__file__` and include the output in the question.

Comment: the same AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a file called `hashlib.py` that gets in the way of the interpreter finding the standard `hashlib` module.

Comment: yes, bro :D thanks, but
How do I? I delete these files?

Comment: @PyDroid Why would you delete that file? Doesn't make any sense. It's your source code. Just rename it so it won't collide with the `haslib` module anymore.

Comment: @PyDroid The only file you may need to delete is the compiled module `hashlib.pyc` in the same directory where you had your `hashlib.py` file, if it was created.

Comment: thanks that helped me i named my file hashlib.py :) oops. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 27):

The problem appeared after installing some brew cask that did some regular cleanup after. Then node-gyp was failing to rebuild some packages for my node application. Reinstalling python 2 helped me.

On macos:

```sh
brew reinstall python@2
```

Comment: Updating python 2 solved my issue, but it seems python@2 has been removed from homebrew. You can still reinstall it as in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60345962/8107620).

Answer (score 3):

### Cause of the error

When you have **a file in the same directory** from where you executed the script (or even if it's the script being run itself) **named the same as a built-in module**, it's loaded instead of the built-in module.

### Fix

To fix it you simply need to rename your file `hashlib.py` to something else and then the Python interpreter will load the built-in module. You may also need to delete the compiled module `hashlib.pyc` which is located in the same directory as your `hashlib.py`, otherwise Python will be still loading that module.

### Explanation

When you `import` a module, let's say `import hashlib`, Python looks for the module `hashlib.py` in the [following locations and in the following order](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

1. directory containing the script being run
2. built-in modules
3. directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified)
4. `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (may contain a list of directories)
5. installation-dependent default path

That means if you execute the script `hashlib.py` which contains the statement `import hashlib`, Python imports the script itself instead of built-in module `hashlib`. In fact, Python compiles your script into the file `hashlib.pyc` in the same directory and imports that compiled script, so if you just rename `hashlib.py` and leave `haslib.pyc` where it is, it will be still loading it. Therefore you also need to delete the `haslib.pyc`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in an anaconda environment after an update of a package which also pulled in a new python version. In my case a `conda remove python` followed by a `conda install python=2.7` fixed this.