# Python 3: Error - Hashlib has no attribute 'SHA256'

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

```
import hashlib    
h = hashlib.SHA256(string)
```

> **Error raised:** AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute
>   'SHA256'

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133167/python-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-sha1) similar to my question:

But my output for **"import hashlib"** and `print(dir(hashlib))` is:

```
['__all__', '__builtin_constructor_cache', '__builtins__', '__cached__', 
'__doc__', '__file__', '__get_builtin_constructor', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_hashlib', 'algorithms_available', 
'algorithms_guaranteed', 'blake2b', 'blake2s', 'md5', 'new', 'pbkdf2_hmac', 
'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha3_224', 'sha3_256', 'sha3_384', 
'sha3_512', 'sha512', 'shake_128', 'shake_256']
```

Comment: Case matters, use sha256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive, meaning the difference between capital letters (upper-case) to lower-case (non capital) letters matters.
Use the names as they appear in your printout, for example `sha256` instead of `SHA256`

So the correct code will be

```
import hashlib    
h = hashlib.sha256(string)
```